# CSS transition not working for changing color

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm currently working on a Wordpress site with the following search template in PHP.

search.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
 * @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/themes/twente.com/style_search_results.css" />

<div class="global-wrap " role="alien-grid" data-grid-cols="4">
        <div class="column full">
            <div class="item maincontent">
                <article class="search-results">

                        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                            <h1> <?php
                                    $mySearch =& new WP_Query("s=$s & showposts=-1");
                                    $num = $mySearch->post_count; ?>

                                    Er zijn <?php echo $num; ?> berichten gevonden.

                                <?php //printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentyfifteen' ), get_search_query() ); ?>
                            </h1>

                            <?php
                            // Start the loop.
                            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                <?php
                                /*
                                 * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
                                 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                                 * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
                                 */
                                get_template_part( 'content', 'search' );

                            // End the loop.
                            endwhile;

                            // Previous/next page navigation.
                            the_posts_pagination( array(
                                'mid_size'              => 2,
                                'prev_text'             => __( 'Vorige pagina', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                                'next_text'             => __( 'Volgende pagina', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                            ) );

                        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                        else :
                            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

                        endif;
                        ?>

                </article>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

content-search.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template part for displaying results in search pages
 *
 * Learn more: {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy}
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
 * @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
 */
?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="search-result">
    <article>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <?php the_excerpt( $more ); ?>

    </article><!-- #post-## -->
</a>
```

This is what I got in the Stylesheet style_search_results.css:

```
a.search-result {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 29px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -25px;
    transition: color 2s;
}

a:hover.search-result {
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

So when I try to hover over the link, it does not change text color. Someone knows a quick fix?

By the way, I am working in Google Chrome.

Comment: a.search-result:hover{color:#0000ff;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

`a.search-result:hover{color:#0000ff}`

**EDIT**

Actual problem was that the a tag had other html tags - we solved it by adding a div container with search-result class

Comment: thats the correct way for handling hover I think the problem is that you have other html tags inside a tag

Comment: can you check my reviewed version and tell me where my mistake is? @vodich

Comment: The problem I have, is that when I enter the block nothing happens. Once I leave the block it fades from blue to black. @vodich

Comment: @Ben do you have online example of this, it is hard helping you at your localhost :)

Comment: I now see that it's working in Internet Explorer.. So it's probably something in Google Chrome, any ideas? @vodich

Comment: Ok what I would do is put the that class on a container div around your text as I suggested , delete the color from the search-result class and you will se changes on hover. just tested it in firefox

Comment: No that's not the solution. It was a stupid fault of myself. I'm working in a team, and someone has set a transition-delay of 2 seconds in the Alien grid which overrules my transition delay. I solved it, but you're solution was right, so thanks :-)

Comment: you guys should use git :)

Comment: we use TortoiseSVN Project Monitor, That works fine, but I was started with this project today. I started at revision 255 of the stylesheet, so that explains a lot ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are giving style is wrong,.

Please try this,

```
a.search-result:hover{color:#0000ff}
```

you can see working [DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/n95qsebt/6/)

Comment: You should remove the whitespace in your code between the class and the :hover.

Answer (score 0):

Stunned that no one here answered this properly ...

use `a.search-result { transition: all 2s ease-in-out; }`

You can also globally assign the transition to work for all properties, which might not be a bad solution.

`a { transition: all 2s ease-in-out; }` though I recommend changing `2s` to `0.3s` or `0.4s`.